# Undoing an old commit

Tags: git, commit, undo

Is possible I undo some old commit? For instance:

```
23-03-2015: Last Commit
22-03-2015: Previous Commit
...
12-03-2015: Changed Login method
11-03-2015: My old Login method
```

I'm working over my `Last Commit`, and on `Changed Login method` I replaced my login method to another one, but for any reason, I need back to my old method, undoning all that I do, but over my `Last Commit`.

```
25-03-2015: Recovered Old Login <--.
...                                |
23-03-2015: Last Commit --------->-+
22-03-2015: Previous Commit        |
...                                |
12-03-2015: Changed Login method   |
11-03-2015: My old Login method ->-'
```

If it helps, I use [**SmartGit**](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/).

Comment: Do you want to just revert all the changes made in `12-03-2015: Changed Login method ` then you can use `git revert <hash of Changed Login method>`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to cherry-pick that commit.

Not sure on SmartGit, but if you Google cherry-pick for SmartGit. Or if you can get to the command line in SmartGit you can type:

```
git cherry-pick 12345
```

Or whatever the commit hash is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check-pick it (oh god). :p

Comment: @DavidRodrigues are you sure you want [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) It applies the changes introduced in the commit again. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Agreed with @Vishwanath - you would ideally revert in this situation. Although both will outcome the same.

Comment: I want to revert an old commit.

Comment: @Vishwanath seems that you comment works for me. Thanks!